# The Latex Companion (Addison-Wesley Series on Tools and Techniques for Computer T) December 31, 1993

Tags: books, learning

I just ordered this book from Amazon, it is the same that my father used ten years ago. Can I still use it for learning LaTeX or I should get the last edition (2007)?

Comment: There have been several changes between the first and second edition; and the book doubled in size. The first edition is a nice antique.

Comment: I would get the 2007 one. I do not find it any of them good for learning LaTeX, but great for looking up stuff when you have forgotten some  syntax details. There is a plethora of good online guides. Here is a good place to start: http://dickimaw-books.com/people/nicola-talbot.html